# Symfony2.1 keep authentication across environments

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

trying to create a separate environment for my symfony2 application and I'd like it to maintain the authenticated user across environments.

currently I have

```
web/app.php (app)
web/cms.php (cms)
```

For the cms I load a bunch of extra modules to edit pages if the user has permission. When I switch from app to the cms environment it drops any authentication done from app and vice versa.

Is there a way to share the authentication token across symfony2 environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the [Remember Me](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) feature.

The other way — which I haven't tried — is to set the session path to one value for all environments. If all your configuration files import `config.yml`, you can do it there:

```
framework:    
    session:
        save_path: /some/path/here
```